# Ajax in JavaServer Faces

Tags: ajax, jsf

I’m trying to use ajax in jsf.
So, I have inputtextarea and datatable:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputTextarea id="mailstextarea" style="width:100%" value="#{newMembersBean.newMembersStr}">
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="newmembertable" execute="mailstextarea" />
    </h:inputTextarea>

    <h:dataTable id="newmembertable" styleClass="tableWidth" value="#{newMembersBean.newMembers}" var="member">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.name}</f:facet>
            #{member.name}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.surename}</f:facet>
            #{member.sureName}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.email}</f:facet>
            #{member.email}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.phone}</f:facet>
            #{member.phone}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="#{msgs.add}"/>
</h:form>
```

I want to change newMembersBean.newMembers List (and datatable newmembertable) on every value change in textarea…
In my bean I’m trying to do somethink like this (now only for testing, I want to show all users, if user have typed more then 3 characters):

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class NewMembersBean implements Serializable {
    private List<UsersEntity> newMembers = new ArrayList<UsersEntity>();
    private String newMembersStr = "";
    ......
    public List<UsersEntity> getNewMembers() {
        UsersDao ud = new UsersDao();
        if(newMembersStr.length() > 3)
        {
            newMembers = ud.getAllUsers();
        }
        return newMembers;
    }
   .....
}
```

But when I’m typing text in textare nothing happens. 
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try widing the scope of the bean to `@SessionScoped`. If that fixes the problem, probably you're not initializing the conversation in the right way.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, that don't fixes problem. Table changes only when I reload page, but not on keyup...

Comment: Try moving the code to retrieve the data from the getter of `newMembers` to the setter of `newMembersStr` and let the `getter` as clean as possible.

Comment: So, it's doesn't help. But what I find. If I change code to this: newMembersStr.length() > 0, then all works fine. And if I add log line in method: System.out.println("GETNEWMEMBERS " + newMembersStr.length()); then, I see this line in log file, only once, on firs keyup. That means, keyup ajax executes only once?